# Move files based on a lookup list into subdirectories

Tags: python, filesystems, move

[Python noob]

I have a parent directory containing hundreds of files pertaining to several records. A text file (names.txt) contains the list of all the records. For every record, there are 5 file types (with different extensions) which all start with the record name as provided in names.txt. I have created a set of subdirectories within the parent, and I intend to move files pertaining to 2 records into 1 subdirectory (Basically, if I have 100 records and 50 subdirectories, I need files of 2 records in each directory. And 2 records*5 files each will be 10 files in each subdirectory).

My names.txt file contains record names in the following format.
170101_T12345678

**edit: While 2 is an arbitrary number, I do want to select records in groups of n. I eventually will run another python job on each of these subfolders, and I don't want to have to process too many records in one subfolder (these are long jobs). I guess I don't even need to do a lookup, if there's a smarter way of just making sure all the 5 files pertaining to those 'n' records will get copied over to one subdirectory. [A lookup will probably just enhance accuracy]. The directories don't need to carry the name of the records in them. They can be anything.

For this example record, there are the following file types pertaining to it:
170101_T12345678.xyz
170101_T12345678.abc
170101_T12345678.klm
170101_T12345678_post.ijk
170101_T12345678_post.opq

One idea I had is to put all the record names in the names.txt into a list, and say for every item in that list --> find the corresponding files --> move them to a specific subdirectory

I was able to generate the list of record names, and I also have some idea on how to move files, but it's the lookup process that I'm very clueless about...

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I think you need to give a little more explanation, but after reading this I think I know what you're trying to say. The difficulty comes from the fact your want two different records in one directory. Why though? Which two? If you can find that correlating factor, you can name the directories based on that and then use that same factor to find them. Elaborate on your question and I'll give a better answer.

Comment: Thanks for your response @GRAYgoose124, I have edited my post - hopefully that helps!

Comment: Given your edit, I think there's not much a good way to do it other than to iterate through the folders one by one looking for a name match. I don't thnk that's an intelligent way to do it. Without a good mechanism. Say for instance, the records inside are sequential, or sequentially based on the record list...then you could do this to look up. How many records in each folder? 3 okay. iterate through the record list 3 records at a time. If it's record 21, then we know it'll be in the 7th subfolder, etc. You need a pattern to enable a lookup. So those folders would need to be sequential too.

Comment: What if I place a .txt file in every subfolder with a list of records I want there. Can I have my script then read that text file, take the records in that into a list, and then lookup those records in the parent directory and move the corresponding files over? [or is that a tall ask!].. Well I guess it was faster to just move them manually than think of a script for it but it would be nice to automate..

Comment: How did you manually move them? Was there an order to it? You could certainly move them, then instead have a txt file at top level which details which records are in which subfolders. then you can search that file for a record and find it's corresponding folder. This will avoid you having to make multiple filesystem requests just for the lookup. That definitely will work. the names.txt could even be the one that holds what subfolder that record is in. That sounds like a good idea.